# Connect to non user calendar with google calendar api

Tags: javascript, api, calendar

I am building a web page for bookings.
This page needs to check one of my public agendas to see if a trailer is available:

[Example event](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&tmeid=bXJvc2Y0MWoxMXEycWk5dm10Nm9pZjFqdmMgN2E5N2Y2azRvazh2NzdqYzJwbzZra2djdW9AZw&tmsrc=7a97f6k4ok8v77jc2po6kkgcuo%40group.calendar.google.com)

I want to use the google calendar API for this purpose, the API needs to give me a list of the dates in the google calendar. For this purpose I made a page based on the google calendar API javascript quickstart.

The only problem is that it loads the calendar of the current user (for example freddi@gmail.com) but I want it to open my calendar (thomas.leflere@gmail.com). How do I modify the google API calendar javascript quickstart code to achieve this goal?

[Google Calendar API Javascript quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample)

Answer (score 0):

The references you've seen involve non-REST APIs. Getting this programatically is possible using a service account. Details on how to create a service account are on Google's page about [two-legged OAuth](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts), a snippet is

> Typically, an application uses a service account when the application
>   uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data.
>   For example, an application that uses Google Cloud Datastore for data
>   persistence would use a service account to authenticate its calls to
>   the Google Cloud Datastore API.

Since this method involves putting a private key on machine initiating the API call, it seems that doing it directly from the browser in JavaScript is not going to be viable. An intermediate server would be needed.

The better alternative for JavaScript would be to invoke an Ajax REST API of a public calendar which is now in version 3. You can find documentation on the API at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/